# Running python subprocess with ubuntu terminal on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openfoam

Is there a way to run the python module `subprocess` under Windows, but using the Ubuntu terminal, that is installed in wsl.

My first guess was to promt the ubuntu terminal via the excutable keyword in the function:

```
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

I need the functionality to be able to run *OpenFOAM* commands with my python programm without immigrating my python code to the Linux system.

**EDIT:**
To clarify my issue a bit further:

I have a GUI with diverse python codes running. From there i need to run OpenFOAM, which is only available under Linux. To overcome that limit, I use Ubuntu (WSL). I would need a WSL shell to run in the background, to execute the linux commands and set up the enviroment needed by OpenFOAM.

Using Ubuntu manually, I start the Terminal and source to the a .bashrc file, where all the enviroment variables are set. From there I can use the OpenFoam commands to run simulations. Those steps would be great to execute from a python code directly.

Comment: I suspect you want to run something *within the WSL* from windows, rather than loading the terminal itself.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/6128

Comment: @2e0byo thanks for the link. Maybe you can help me a bit further. When working regular with the terminal, I would load an .bashrc file to set up the enviroment variables needed by OpenFOAM, using the command _source /opt/openfoam8/etc/bashrc_. Is it possible to set up a temporary enviroment with the "wsl.exe" command, or is only possible to execute single commands?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A few questions to help me understand your use case - Do you mean that you want to run the *Windows* Python `subprocess` module under WSL?  You say *"without migrating my Python code to the Linux system."*  So what is it exactly that you want to run in WSL?  Are you just wanting the WSL "terminal" (I think you mean "shell") while still using your Windows Python code?

Comment: I have a GUI with diverse python codes running. From there i need to run OpenFOAM, which is only available under Linux. To overcome that limit, I use Ubuntu (WSL). So yes i would need a WSL shell to run in the background, to execute the linux commands and set up the enviroment needed by OpenFOAM.

Comment: I am fortunately not able to test this, but try passing `shell=True, executable='/path/to/wsl.exe'`. You can pass in `source /path/to/etc/bashrc; yourcommand --options` or perhaps refactor your Python script to populate the environment before the call.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone else on that problem:

My workaround for the problem is, that i create a .sh file in my wsl file that i compile with `wsl chmod -x filename.sh` and then run it with `source filename.sh`.

Inside my .sh file i load the enviromental variables of OpenFoam by sourcing to the bashrc file of the OpenFoam version that i want to use in my script. From there, I can define each step, that would i normally do in the terminal. (Similar to the Allrun files in the OpenFoam examples)

Comment: I am very interested in your workaround. I am trying to develop a python GUI to send OpenFOAM commands under WSL. I tried your solution but seems to me the environment generated is not persistent. Did you find a way to send OpenFOAM command after setting the environment?