# Python os.system() uses cmd on windows, any ways I can change to my ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, linux, import, cmd, terminal

I feel uncomfortable using cmd and I want to use commands for my python scripts, wondering if there is any way to not use cmd for os.system() and instead changes that to my ubuntu terminal. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're suing WSL to run ubuntu. So why not just launch `wsl.exe` in a subprocess and pass the command as args to it? Does it really have to be a call to `os.system()`?

Comment: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since many years as it results on Windows in running `%ComSpec% /c` with the command line specified in Python code appended as additional argument(s). There is the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which gives the Python programmer full control over how an executable is run from within a Python script.

Comment: There is used on Windows directly the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure on using the `subprocess module`. The function `CreateProcess` is used also by `os.system` to start `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the arguments and used by `cmd.exe` to run the executable(s) specified on the command line.

Comment: In other words the usage of `os.system()` is just a roundabout route to run executables using `CreateProcess` without having control over the function parameters and the values in `STARTUPINFO` structure in comparison to `subprocess.Popen()` giving the Python script programmer full control over all parameters which can be used on Windows on starting an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), `os.system(<command>)` executes `<command>` in a subshell, which is system dependent. There is no way to make `os.system()` run a Windows specific command as a Unix equivalent. You may be interested in Python's [sys module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

If you edit your question with more specific details as to what commands you are trying to run I might be able to provide better help.

Answer (score 0):

os.system() normally runs system commands depending the OS you are running the script.
However, you can read this article on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455685/running-python-subprocess-with-ubuntu-terminal-on-windows) or try to follow further steps to setup an effective environment for Python on Ubuntu on Windows.

> 1. Install Bash on Windows
> 2. Check for updates
> 3. Check out the REPL
> 4. Install Pip
> 5. Install VirtualEnv
> 6. Install VirtualEnvWrapper
> 7. Create your first virtualenv
> 8. Configure bashrc to keep it working
>    More detailes [here](https://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-with-ubuntu-on-windows/)